# I can't upvote comments to nominations in the Ask Ubuntu Election!

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, election

An [election has just begun](https://askubuntu.com/election/2) over on Ask Ubuntu. There is currently one nomination with 4 comments (one of which is mine). **However,** I can't upvote any of the last three - clicking the upvote arrow doesn't do anything.

Popping open the Chrome Inspector reveals nothing - no errors, no network requests, nothing.

I am using Chrome 16.0.912.77 m.

Comment: I cannot upvote any of the comments either. Firefox 9, Windows 7.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer possible to upvote comments on moderator election nominations by design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was my bug - I recently added some comment linking to the Question/Show and StackExchange inbox and forgot this would affect the election page.

Fixed and deployed.

Comment: DEMOCRACY CANNOT BE STOPPED!

Comment: This is broken again..

Comment: @ɥʇǝS not only broken, [but completely removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination) - not sure why we disabled nomination comment voting.  Asking around about it.

Comment: @JarrodDixon It would be *really* awesome if this could be fixed. Currently there is no way to show agreement with another content except by adding a new comment.