# Cannot upvote comments under an election nomination

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, comments, election

In current moderator elections such as the [Math election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5), I can't upvote comments. I've also been told by higher rep users and moderators that they can't upvote comments either. I know this was possible in the [2014 Stack Overflow Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5), as you can see by the large number of upvotes on almost all of the comments.

Was the ability to upvote comments underneath a nomination removed for a reason? Or is this just a bug?

Comment: I know the ability to flag was removed for a reason, maybe upvoting came along with it?

Comment: @Undo Naw we had upvotes without flags for a while.

Comment: Maybe the return of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120777/i-cant-upvote-comments-to-nominations-in-the-ask-ubuntu-election)?

Comment: I think it's by design. In this context I prefer comments without votes, personally. Otherwise the groups of supporters can influence the display of comments without having anything to contribute to the discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was taken out a while back [along with flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221045/155160).

Nobody seems to recall exactly what went bust there once flagging was taken out, but for  the moment this is by design.

Comment: Well, [not all is lost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245124/i-can-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination-even-though-there-is-no-gui-f). :)

Comment: I want my comment votes back *pouts* :(