# Can *too* upvote comments under an election nomination

Tags: support, bug, comments, user-interface, election

Apparently, [we're not supposed to be able to upvote comments in moderator elections any more.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination)

Only, it turns out that you *can*, if you just know how:

> [image: Screenshot of upvoted comment in moderator election]

Basically, it's [yet another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments) back-end [validation issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215229/i-can-dispute-flags-without-10k-rep-and-so-can-you): while the upvote *button* is missing from the page HTML, the SE back-end is still happy to accept and display upvotes for election comments, so all you need to do to restore the missing functionality is to edit the page HTML in your browser's dev tools and paste in the code for the upvote button from some other page.

---

What I'm not sure about is whether the *actual bug* is that we *can* upvote election comments like this, or that we (supposedly) cannot.  Specifically, while the bug report above (about the inability to upvote election comments) is marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), [Anna Lear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination/245032#245032) to it seems to suggest that it may not be *really* by design (*emphasis* mine):

> This was taken out a while back [along with flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221045/155160).
>
> Nobody seems to recall exactly what went bust there once flagging was taken out, but *for the moment this is by design.*

So, is it by design or not?  Did somebody decide that comment votes on election nominations are bad and should not be allowed, or was it just a side effect of disabling comment *flags* that the devs decided not to bother fixing?  Who knows?

The thing is, I'd kind of *like to* know, before I add the code I wrote to restore the upvote buttons into [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch). :)

Comment: But can you still flag? My guess is they removed the flag option both server side and client side, and didn't expect the client side would also bring upvoting down.

Comment: Wow! I'm going to be popular!

Comment: At least we can all agree it was a comment worthy of being upvoted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You seem to be right about flagging: I can bring up the flagging dialog and submit it, but the flag gets rejected by the server.

Comment: Ps. Aww, @ShadowWizard, you ruined my [subtle intertextual reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination) in the title. :)

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the pun! Feel free to rollback. :)

Comment: Yay, I love hacks!

Comment: Hrm. I'm gonna check with the community team to see what we want to do in the end. In the meantime, please don't add this to SOUP cause that'd just be majorly weird for the vast majority of users who, you know, don't run your extension. :)

Comment: @Anna: OK, I won't. :) But if you want my input, I really would like to see the ability to vote on election comments restored. I do feel that it helps to organize the commentary, and to reduce the temptation to post "me too" comments.

Comment: @Anna: Did you ever get any feedback from the community team on this?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen This needs to be fixed on our end. Providing upvotes via userscript is definitely a non-starter - confusing to everyone who doesn't know about it, if nothing else.

Comment: @Anna: OK, but just to clarify, there *are* plans to restore the voting interface for election comments, right? Or did I read too much between the lines in your reply?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Honestly... the immediate fix will likely be to disable the voting. I personally miss it, but making it work is apparently non-trivial. :/

Comment: Then again, disabling upvotes might also turn out to be hard. Depends on what assumptions we're making... We'll see.

Comment: @Anna: Well, :(. Do you think it would help if I sent you a JS patch to restore the missing vote buttons? (I'd have to rewrite it, since I don't think I still have the code I wrote for the math.SE election, but it really wasn't very complicated.)

Comment: Nah, it's okay. Thanks. :) Restoring the physical buttons isn't a big problem. You know, as I think more about it... I think the voting/flagging logic has changed since the upvoting was taken out for election comments. In a good way - might be able to get upvotes going again. No promises, but I'll look.

Comment: @Anna: Well, back when I posted this question, restoring the buttons really *was* all that was needed. It looks like something has changed in the back-end over the last 4 months, though; I just rewrote the script I used, and I can still *try to* upvote election comments, but I'm now getting an error saying that "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging." Oh well, I'll mail you a link to the script anyway.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Sounds good, thanks. Might be that I'm way out of the loop on the current state of things. Don't have the code in front of me, so who knows. :)

Comment: Upon inspection, this *appears* to have been patched server side. The result of the action comes from an http response body and is clearly blocking the ability to upvote the comment. This could mean that it is no-repro. *However*, it is also possible that all voting was blocked when the election ended, and when a different election begins voting will be enabled and that will include comment voting as well.

Comment: @TravisJ: Looks like somebody managed to upvote [this election comment on GD.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination#comment-71980) less than a week ago, but I can't upvote it anymore, either. (The GD.SE election just switched from the primary to the final election phase.) The SO election just entered the nomination phase, so I guess we'll find out if any upvotes appear there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Was able to reproduce this in the SO moderation post (sorry). I believe that the entire post being locked in the previous situations is what led to a false belief (on my part as well) of this issue having been handled. Status-Repro in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, [I see](http://stackoverflow.com/election/6?tab=nomination#comment-47119112). @AnnaLear, looks like the back-end still accepts votes *during the nomination phase*, so the JS code I sent you is literally all that's needed to re-enable voting.

Comment: I was going to post this same report. Some users *have* been using this in the current election. I totally don't fault them, but I think at minimum the score *display* (and unexpanded comment display selection) needs to be disabled, even if the score itself can't be easily disabled in the back-end. I really don't like the idea of being able to draw attention to specific comments in any of the election phases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Voting for comments has been disabled during the nomination phase for now.  We want to make sure that we are at consistent when it comes to elections.

Comment: This is sad because I think comment voting is a very important feature when it comes to elections. *Very* important.

Comment: You will still be able to vote for comments, just not in the nomination phase of an election.

Comment: I'm confused. Your post and comment contradict each other.. Can you clarify?

Comment: Voting for comments in the nomination phase is disabled, voting during other election phases should work as it did before.

Comment: That seems.. Pointless. It isn't easy to add comments during the other phases. Why allow voting on comments at all then?

Comment: This is sad because comment voting is a very important feature when it comes to elections. *Very* important.

Comment: ^ reposted what Seth said since I couldn't upvote

Comment: Ditto on what Seth (and Roombatron) said. Also, voting on comments during the final election phase appears to be impossible anyway, since the nominations are locked then, so basically you're saying that we can now *only* vote on election comments during the primary (if there is any)?

Comment: For a real-world example of the point @Roombatron5000 is illustrating, see [Raghav Sood's nomination](http://stackoverflow.com/election/6#post-29484189).

Comment: @BoltClock: Indeed. Just in case some mod comes along and cleans that up, [I saved a screenshot.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZEou.png)

Comment: You also *can't see* comments on the primary & election tabs (you have to switch back to the nomination tab)... so this doesn't really make sense.