# Please allow me to wear my hat upside down

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I want to wear my hat upside down but the rotate control seems to be fixed so I can't.

Please remove this terrible restriction so that I can use hats as they weren't intended! :-)

See also the excellent examples in this duplicate question: [Let us be more creative with our hat placement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245732/let-us-be-more-creative-with-our-hat-placement)

Comment: [Here you go](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AYbRk.png) ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard  are you a wiz....

nvm.

Comment: @ShadowWizard much better, thanks!

Comment: You know, it's just a few weeks of *fun*...

Comment: Eh, it would be super confusing if you'll put that as avatar then wear the hat... ;D

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Done!

Comment: I think they're just saving enhancements for each successive year: First hats, then moveable hats, then sizeable and rotatable, then.... upside down! After that who knows, maybe animated secret hats!?!

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett animated hats would be super... but think too many people would hate them! Oh, and nice double hat you got now. Looks like an android-sandwich. :-P

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah, can't see that happening. Not sure I'd want it either! lol

Comment: @David how come you don't have the boat? I was under the impression staff got it by default...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So it seems the community's stand on this is pretty clear. Internally, we were a bit more divided – here are some quotes from our chat room:

- "there's no technical reason to constrain it, but I don't feel you should be able to rotate all the way"
- "They're not really *hats* anymore, then, are they? More like just random avatar decorating sticker thingamabobbers."
- "I do not care about this decision, even a little bit. Whatever you all want is fine."
- "MULLET BEARDS!"
- "I'd say go for it."

– and that last quote is from [Jon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson), who's the hat master this year, and thus what the heck: Rotate all you want!

Comment: Epic! As soon as I can get to a pc I'll experiment with all the new possibilities. And they definitely still are hats. :)

Comment: "*They're not really hats anymore, then, are they?*" - as if a boat is a hat, really!

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg [It's not, you say?...](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yKX7e_C0n70/UGXoQjZwhII/AAAAAAAAFJw/ZIxmJJJ02pI/s1600/Hairsty+at+NY+Worlds+Fair+c+1939+via+B+&+WTF.jpg)

Comment: @Laura I guess that's Abby herself on the picture, huh?

Comment: Whoever said "mullet beards", and "avatar decorating sticker thingamabobbers" *gets it*.

Comment: I'm mulletbeard and I approve this message.

Comment: @balpha time to put on that sweet ass soccer necklace ;)

Comment: @CarrieKendall I'm a fairly conservative guy. In public, I prefer to wear my oversized <s>soccer</s> football-shaped wearables on top of my had. Everything would be just silly.

Comment: Can we guess who said what? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Be my guest, but don't expect a hat for guessing correctly.

Comment: #1: Geoff (or you ;)). #2: Shog. #3: Joel. #4: Abby?

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Now my [hairboat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/hairboat) finally looks like an actual hat! :)

Answer (score 22):

Yes, please. Thats abnormal to wear hatz upside-downside-up or downside-upside-down. They should be worn upside down or at least downside up.

[image]

<sup><sup>[source](http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02153/china-police_2153775i.jpg)</sup></sup>

Answer (score 10):

Agreed! Especially for the not-as-hat-looking hats (e.g., Time Lord) this would be useful. When is the TARDIS *not* upside down?

Comment: I'm pretty sure The Doctor would construct an argument about there not being any such thing as right-side-up.

Comment: The Tardis is always the right side up. It's the rest of the universe which is inverted.

Answer (score 9):

It's probably too late for this time around, but this could be considered for next year's event.

But hey... [what do *I* know, anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245795/165581)?

Comment: Not sure how it would be "too late" to make a simple change to the rotation angle limits. Unless you mean "the devs who wrote the code all left for holidays already"? ;)

Comment: hooray! \o/ next year the mulletstache will be legalized

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Nope, I'm still here :) And it's not quite as simple, because there are a few things with the hat placement UI that would need to be changed in order to accomodate full rotation. Not as simple as replacing "60°" with "180°" (but not really hard either).

Comment: Also have to make sure the gerbils dont fall off the wheels or the servers would go offline :-P

Comment: Would it be possible to greasemonkey it? I'm thinking that could possibly maybe work, but I'm no greasemonkey expert.

Comment: Is this the spot where I can ask for animated hats?!?

Comment: Glad to see this feature implemented!

Comment: Um... it has been implemented, as far as I can tell

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Yeah, but if it would work in greasemonkey, it would only work for *you*, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Shokhet: Before this was implemented, I did try to see the server might accept out-of-bounds hat angles even if the hat adjustment UI didn't allow them. Alas, it turned out that it didn't, so a user script fix wasn't possible.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Ah. I see.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Not sure whether I should be offended by the assumption that I could've forgotton to check the data serverside ;p

Comment: @balpha: Maybe not *you*, but not all your colleagues seem to be quite as diligent about that. I figured it might at [least](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments) be [worth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215229/i-can-dispute-flags-without-10k-rep-and-so-can-you) a [shot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245124/can-too-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination). :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Fair enough. But here we're talking about critical functionality like **hats**, not minor things like access to deleted data.

Comment: Comment for Hairboat :p

Comment: so apparently there are hairboat hats huh :P

Answer (score 5):

You don't want that.  It would look ridiculous.

Comment: ...," says the guy currently wearing his top hat upside-down. :P

Comment: Irony is dead, kids.

Comment: Until next year! :)