# Let us be more creative with our hat placement

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash

So, safe to say, I am fairly addicted to the hats. They are a lot of fun and their silliness is addictive.

In the spirit of the winterbash, I am hoping we can be allowed to have more control of hat positioning. After asking for a downvote in chat so I could get that babe mullet, I wondered if I could give myself a mullet-beard but it won't allow 360 degree rotation.

Just think of all the absurd things we are missing out on!

[image: Sweet ass soccer necklace] 
<sub>Sweet ass soccer necklace</sub>

[image: mulletbeard] 
<sub>Mulletbeard™</sub>

[image: crab face googly eyes] 
<sub>Crab face googly eyes</sub>

[image: next generation earpiece] 
<sub>iPhone Plus Plus</sub>

Now sure, some nay sayers will say *"but they're hats!"*... If you're concerned with keeping them as hats, it's too late! I am already [mulletstaching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/179335/carrie-kendall) it up. Furthermore, when I get tired of my stache, I switch out to crab eyes so, **resistance is futile**!

Comment: @ShadowWizard fair enough, but I am asking for 360 degrees ;)

Comment: lol... well, hope your request will give the required nudge! (no official response so far)

Comment: I hope so. I mean look at that sweet ass soccer necklace!

Comment: Yup, we should also get hat for supreme photoshop skillz! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard and other cv-ers, I added a high-tech ear piece picture to differentiate the posts. I am not only asking to flip it upside down. I greedily want 360 degrees!

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but the other question does specifically claim that the "rotate control seems to be fixed" (as in you cannot go past a certain angle) and for the removal of said restriction. Mulletstashing, however, is clearly unique to this post.

Comment: Pft, read the title. This clearly is way different ;)

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate purely for the example images.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi no need to be able to answer in order to have those images. She can safely keep adding awesome examples (and collect shiny repz) even while the question is closed. ;-)

Comment: You nay sayers and your damned rules!

Comment: Oh wait, iPhone plus plus? Was ist das?

Comment: Rules are rules, even during winter, during bash, and during hatz. :-P

Comment: Fun _murdered_. Good game, meta. Back to my corner where I debate why I try :P

Comment: Respect! Stack Exchange Chief Developer (aka David) linked to your samples. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245795/115866 You won ;)

Comment: Yay! Shirt hat!

Comment: @ShadowWizard don't abuse the phone plus plus hat! ;)

Comment: Phone for one is a hat for other! :D