# Can we someday wear multiple hats?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

Part of the fun of hats is not just earning them, but wearing them (preferably in [amusing and creative ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245732/let-us-be-more-creative-with-our-hat-placement)). I particularly appreciated the addition of size/position/rotation controls a few years ago.

Would it ever be possible to have my avatar wear multiple hats? e.g....

[image: this is fire]
*oh no, I have set myself on fire trying to light the menorah*

Comment: Well... +1 just for that pic. Priceless.

Comment: That ava. BEST ava

Comment: You can already wear multiple hats, but only the last one is changeable :)